# Do both branches and tags both -- literally speaking -- refer to commits?

Tags: git

In git, tags refer to commits. So what, literally speaking, does a branch refer to?

I know that, intuitively speaking, I think of a branch as a set of related commits, but is that the correct way to think about them?

Comment: what commit a branch points to is dynamic, e.g. it moves forward when you make a commit. a tag is just a tag for a specific commit.

Comment: But is it true that branches always refer to a specific *commit* (even though this commit reference can change)?

Comment: if you go to `code-name/.git/refs/heads` you will see a file named after the branch, which contains only a hash number, which is what commit the branch points to. that is all what branch is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch refers to the tip of a commit history: all the commits accessible from that particular branch head (written in `.git/refs/heads/abranch`).

[image]

<sup>(image from Atlassian [Using Branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch) tutorial)</sup>

This "accessibility" characteristic result from the [DAG nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) the commits

[image: DAG]

<sup>from [Git: an introduction](http://git.mikeward.org/)</sup>

[image: DAG bis]

Comment: The article you referenced answered my question: "Git stores a branch as a reference to a commit. In this sense, a branch represents the tip of a series of commits—it's not a container for commits."

Comment: @George yes, that is why my answer starts with "refers to the tip of a commit history"

Comment: DAGs are not "usually called 'trees'" because not all DAGs are trees.

Comment: In fact, almost all non-linear histories in a branch in git are *not* trees: if you have a merge commit, then it is highly unusual for its parents not to have a common ancestor.

Comment: *[...] all the commits accessible from that particular branch HEAD.* I think you should use lowercase "head"; uppercase "head" can too easily be misinterpreted as the symbolic reference of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** if I understand your question correctly.

In Git, a branch and a tag are both just names which point to commits.  The major difference between them is just user interface.  You can browse both branches and tags in the `.git/refs` directory.  Note that tags can also have annotations.

Answer (score 0):

A branch is a way of seperating your commits.

Generally speaking if you put commits on a seperate branch from master, you are testing experimental code, which you don't want to have on your main master branch (master is mostly stable and release code). Once your experimental code is deemed stable you can merge the branch into your master. This means that your master branch now has the previously stable code and your new previously experimental code.

Another way to use branches is if you have some modularity in your program. Eg: Input handling classes/ File Handling classes etc. If you co op on a project with this structure, one person can have his Input handling adjustments on a seperate branch, and idem dito for the file handling adjustments.
This makes for cleaner commit lines.
Also this means that you can work without having to have the (probably) unstable commited code from your buddy in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation, it's really helpful. [Git branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell), [Git tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

To answer your question.
Tagging is to give some specific name to a commit, in order to make your project's history easier to understand. It's useful if you need (or want) to do a rollback to a specific version of your project.

Branch are more complete (and complex) things. When you create a new branch you "fork" your project. It's mean you can work on both branch in different ways and your commit of the branch A will not interfere in your branch B.

This can be useful in many case. For example, when you work in team, everybody as to do a part of the project, so they created a branch for each part, and then they merge everything. Or when your work for a software support, for each issue you will create a branch, and when you fixed it you merge it with the branch master. Or,...

Comment: Thinking of branches this way leads to many confused questions here on SO.  A branch is just a repo-local label.  So far as git's concerned, commits matter. All else is just local interpretation.  Abstractions are like street lamps: they only help in the dark, and if you try to get by with just one, you're not going to get very far.  Better to operate in daylight.